# Use a web page as an input for a C# project

Tags: c#, html, web

How do I scan (as in scanf (from C) and the Scanner class (from Java)) in a webpage's content (html) and use it as  the input for my program?

```
string[] line = new string[length];
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) {
  line[i] = Console.ReadLine();
  //Can I have ReadLine read from a website not the Console?
}
```

e.g. I want to put a text file containing the schedules for the bus near me on web server, then access this and use it to generate the output for my application. This way I can update it and always have access to these updates.

P.S. I'm a beginning programmer, and particularly a beginning C# programmer, so I'm having trouble finding what I'm looking for as I don't know quite what to search for.

Thanks for the help: I was able to start searching for the right thing and this worked:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // Create web client.
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        // Download string.
        string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com");

        // Write values.
        Console.WriteLine("--- WebClient result ---");
        Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Search terms: "web scraping" and "C# WebClient download". Please do research and than ask concrete questions with sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Test()
{
    string pageData = DownloadWebPage(new Uri("http://www.yourftp.com"));
    //parse data
}

private string DownloadWebPage(Uri path)
{
    string webPageData = null;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadStringAsync(path);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => webPageData = args.Result;
    }

    return webPageData;
}
```

You can use the method above to download the text file from your web server once it has uploaded. Just pass the URI to the `DownloadWebPage` method and it will return the text page. If you want help parsing the text document to provide meaningful C# representations you will need to give an example of the text file and describe how you want to parse it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to follow a search for WebClient and find what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the content by a URL and then load it into an HTML document using something like the HTML Agility Pack.  See this SO thread for suggestions [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)